# Alinear links de menu en Tailwind css

Tags: tailwind

Llevo varias horas buscando como alinear los links de un menú y tengo que recurrir a ustedes por que aún estoy muy fresco con Tailwind.

> El menú se ve así

Deseo alinear a la izquierda la hamburguesa de categorías

```
{{-- MENU HAMBURGUERS CATEGORIAS --}}
    <a class="flex flex-col col-end-6 items-center justify-center px-4 bg-white bg-opacity-25 text-white cursor-pointer font-semibold h-full">
        <svg class="h-6 w-6" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <path class="inline-flex" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16" />
        </svg>

        <span>Categorías</span>
    </a>
```

Si saco la clase justify-between en el div de la segunda linea:

```
<div class="container flex items-center justify-between h-16">
```

Se ve de la siguiente manera:

Pero de esta manera no puedo alinear a la derecha las opciones **acceder** y **registrarse**

> El menú completo

```
<div class="container flex items-center h-16">
    
    {{-- LOGOTIPO --}}
    <a href="/" class="flex-shrink-0 mr-6 flex items-center">
        <img class="block lg:hidden h-12 w-auto" src="{{ asset('img/logoB.png')}}" alt="Workflow">
        <img class="hidden lg:block h-12 w-auto" src="{{ asset('img/logoB.png')}}" alt="Workflow">
    </a>
    {{-- FIN LOGOTIPO --}}

    {{-- MENU HAMBURGUERS CATEGORIAS --}}
    <a class="flex flex-col col-end-6 items-center justify-center px-4 bg-white bg-opacity-25 text-white cursor-pointer font-semibold h-full">
        <svg class="h-6 w-6" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <path class="inline-flex" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16" />
        </svg>

        <span>Categorías</span>
    </a>
    {{-- MENU HAMBURGUERS CATEGORIAS --}}

    {{-- LOGIN y OPCIONES --}}
    @auth
        <div class="absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center pr-2 sm:static sm:inset-auto sm:ml-6 sm:pr-0">
            
            <!-- Boton notificaciones -->
            <button class="bg-blue-800 p-1 rounded-full text-gray-400 hover:text-white focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-offset-gray-800 focus:ring-white">
                <svg class="h-6 w-6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M15 17h5l-1.405-1.405A2.032 2.032 0 0118 14.158V11a6.002 6.002 0 00-4-5.659V5a2 2 0 10-4 0v.341C7.67 6.165 6 8.388 6 11v3.159c0 .538-.214 1.055-.595 1.436L4 17h5m6 0v1a3 3 0 11-6 0v-1m6 0H9" />
                </svg>
            </button>

            <!-- Profile dropdown -->
            <div class="ml-3 relative" x-data="{ open:false }">
                <div>
                    <button x-on:click="open = !open" type="button" class="bg-gray-800 flex text-sm rounded-full focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-offset-gray-800 focus:ring-white" id="user-menu-button" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true">
                        <img class="h-8 w-8 rounded-full" src="{{ auth()->user()->profile_photo_url }}" alt="Imagen de perfil">
                    </button>
                </div>
                
                <div x-show="open" x-on:click.away="open = !open" class="origin-top-right absolute right-0 mt-2 w-48 rounded-md shadow-lg py-1 bg-white ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none" role="menu" aria-orientation="vertical" aria-labelledby="user-menu-button" tabindex="-1">
                    <a href="{{ route('profile.show') }}" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" id="user-menu-item-0">Perfil</a>
                    
                    {{-- PERMISO ADMIN.HOME INFO: https://youtu.be/Ox3WRl6sJrw?list=PLZ2ovOgdI-kX3XFj77zlvSQYhJyJSYQWr&t=134 --}}
                    @can('admin.home')
                        <a href="{{ route('admin.home') }}" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" id="user-menu-item-0">Administrador</a>
                    @endcan
                    
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('logout') }}">
                    @csrf
                        <a href="{{ route('logout') }}" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" id="user-menu-item-2" onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                    this.closest('form').submit();">
                            Cerrar sesión
                        </a>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @else
        <div>
            <a href="{{route('login')}}" class="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium">Acceder</a>
            <a href="{{route('register')}}" class="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium">Registrarse</a>
        </div>
    @endauth
    {{-- FIN LOGIN Y OPCIONES --}}

</div>
```

Estaré muy agradecido a toda persona que me pueda brindar una idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes considerar lo siguiente:

1. Divide el menú en 2 listas desordenadas
2. Al contenedor principal le das las clases necesarias que ayuden a colocar los contenedores internos de manera horizontal y separados colocándolos en los extremos (*flex y justify-between*)
3. Las mismas acciones del paso anterior las repites para los contenedores **`ul`** (*flex y justify-around*), además de darle un ancho para *notar* la separación de los **`li`**.

Código de ejemplo:

```
<nav class="bg-gray-400 
            text-white
            flex 
            font-bold 
            justify-between">
  <ul class="flex justify-around w-3/12">
    <li>Logo</li>
    <li>Categorías</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="flex justify-around w-3/12">
    <li>Acceder</li>
    <li>Registrarse</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! lo solucione en base a tu comentario! buenas noches